# Is there a more efficient way to implement the model below in Python's Pyomo?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I want to implement the following model in Pyomo which is a minimal example of the problem I am confronted with:

[image]

As the data I work with has a large number of set elements for IJK, JKL, and KLM, I need an efficient implementation for summing over my x variables that satisfy the index mapping ((j,k) in IJK and (j,k,l) in JKL and (k,l,m) in KLM). Iterating over all elements of sets IJK, JKL, and KLM seems to become inefficient as the cardinality of these sets increases.

The best performing implementation I came up with is as follows:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo

def model(I, IJK, JKL, KLM):
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

    model.I = pyo.Set(initialize=I)
    model.IJK = pyo.Set(initialize=IJK)
    model.JKL = pyo.Set(initialize=JKL)
    model.KLM = pyo.Set(initialize=KLM)

    model.z = pyo.Param(default=1)

    x_list = [(i, j, k, l, m) for (i, j, k) in model.IJK
              for (jj, kk, l) in model.JKL if (jj == j) and (kk == k)
              for (kkk, ll, m) in model.KLM if (kkk == k) and (ll == l)]

    model.x_list = pyo.Set(initialize=x_list)

    model.x = pyo.Var(model.x_list, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

    model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr=model.z)

    model.ei = pyo.Constraint(model.I, rule=ei_rule)


def ei_rule(model, i):
    lhs = [model.x[k] for k in model.x_list if k[0] == i]
    if len(lhs) == 0:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return sum(lhs) >= 0
```

Here is code to produce random data for the model:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def create_random_data(n, m):
    I = [f'i{x}' for x in range(1, n + 1)]
    J = [f'j{x}' for x in range(1, m + 1)]
    K = [f'k{x}' for x in range(1, m + 1)]
    L = [f'l{x}' for x in range(1, m + 1)]
    M = [f'm{x}' for x in range(1, m + 1)]

    ijk = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.05, size=(len(I)*len(J)*len(K))),
                       index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                           [I, J, K], names=['i', 'j', 'k']),
                       columns=['value']).reset_index()
    jkl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.05, size=(len(J)*len(K)*len(L))),
                       index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                           [J, K, L], names=['j', 'k', 'l']),
                       columns=['value']).reset_index()
    klm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.05, size=(len(K)*len(L)*len(M))),
                       index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                           [K, L, M], names=['k', 'l', 'm']),
                       columns=['value']).reset_index()

    IJK = [tuple(x) for x in ijk.loc[ijk['value'] == 1]
           [['i', 'j', 'k']].to_dict('split')['data']]
    JKL = [tuple(x) for x in jkl.loc[jkl['value'] == 1]
           [['j', 'k', 'l']].to_dict('split')['data']]
    KLM = [tuple(x) for x in klm.loc[klm['value'] == 1]
           [['k', 'l', 'm']].to_dict('split')['data']]
    return I, J, K, L, M, IJK, JKL, KLM
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement the introduced model in Pyomo?

```py
I, J, K, L, M, IJK, JKL, KLM = create_random_data(300, 20) 
%timeit -r 7 -n 10 model(I, IJK, JKL, KLM)
```

`Out: 582 ms ± 65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension takes significant amount of time:

```
    x_list = [(i, j, k, l, m) for (i, j, k) in model.IJK
              for (jj, kk, l) in model.JKL if (jj == j) and (kk == k)
              for (kkk, ll, m) in model.KLM if (kkk == k) and (ll == l)]
```

It can be improved if you takes dicts instead of sets/lists.

```
    IJK = [tuple(x) for x in ijk.loc[ijk['value'] == 1]
           [['i', 'j', 'k']].to_dict('split')['data']]
    JKL = defaultdict(list)
    for x in jkl.loc[jkl['value'] == 1][['j', 'k', 'l']].to_dict('split')['data']:
        JKL[tuple(x[:2])].append(x[2])
    KLM = defaultdict(list)
    for x in klm.loc[klm['value'] == 1][['k', 'l', 'm']].to_dict('split')['data']:
        KLM[tuple(x[:2])].append(x[2])
```

and build `x_list` as

```
    x_list = [(i, j, k, l, m) for (i, j, k) in IJK
              for l in JKL[j, k]
              for m in KLM[k, l]]
```

Same with

```
def ei_rule(model, i):
    lhs = [model.x[k] for k in model.x_list if k[0] == i]
    if len(lhs) == 0:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return sum(lhs) >= 0
```

It seesm to be faster to generate such thing manually.

```
    x_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for x in x_list:
        x_dict[x[0]].append(x)
    model.ei = pyo.ConstraintList()
    for x_values in x_dict.values():
        model.ei.add(sum(model.x[k] for k in x_values) >= 0)
```

Also, why do not you skip `len(lhs) == 1`? You are already have these constraints. This would give additional speed up.

With all tricks above I got about 4x speed up. I did not check with larger data. It can be worse or better. But I believe that you need to compare with solving time. And start to worry if modeling is slower than solving time.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the suggestions in the other solution which are great in reducing the large comprehensions, you should also consider using an indexed set in the construction of your constraint.  By doing so, you can remove all of the list comprehensions you are doing "on the fly" inside the constraint construction and this should have a significant speedup on the model construction, somewhat proportional to `|I|`.  This:

```
i_ijklm = {ii: ((i, j, k, l, m) for (i, j, k, l, m) in x_list if i==ii) for ii in I}

model.i_ijklm = pyo.Set(model.I, initialize=i_ijklm)

def ei_rule(model, i):
    return sum(model.x[ijklm] for ijklm in model.i_ijklm[i]) >= 0
```

You could tinker with the dictionary vs. nested comprehension on this part as well

Comment: Thanks @Mafii. The only problem that I have with the dictionary approach is that I need a new dictionary depending on how I access my indexes. Suppose I have another equation summing over `x[i,j,k,l,m]` where `(j,k,l) in JKL` and `(k,l,m) in KLM` for all valid combinations of `(j,l)`. Using dictionaries I would need `constraint_dict_jl = defaultdict(list)` & `for i,j,k,l,m in x_list: constraint_dict_jl[j,l].append((i,j,k,l,m))`. Am I right? In my (non-minimal-working-example) this leeds to a lot of additional sets. However, the dictionary approach still seems to be more efficient.